How to efficiently toggle components using Mithril.js
I have a list of some data. I want to display and edit that data.
My Home component iterates over this data and display using Item component it Each row has data and edit button. After clicking on edit it displays the EditItem component which is used to edit data.
It is working fine. But I think it renders whole Home component when I edit item. Is there any better way to do it?


// Item component
var Item = {
    view: function(vnode) {
        return m("tr", [
            m("td", vnode.attrs.id),
            m("td", vnode.attrs.text),
            m("td", m("button", {onclick: function() {
                vnode.attrs.edit(vnode.attrs.index);
            }}, "Edit"))
        ]);
    }
}

// EditItem component
function EditItem(vnode) {
    var value =  vnode.attrs.text // save value of text
    return {view: function(vnode) {
        return m("tr", [
            m("td", vnode.attrs.id),
            m("td", m("input", {value: value, oninput: (e)=> {                value = e.target.value
            }})),
            m("td", m("button", {onclick: function() {
                vnode.attrs.save(value);
            }}, "Save"))
        ]);
    }}
}

// Home component
var Home = {
    view: function() {
        return m("div", [
            m("table", {border: 1}, [
                m("thead", [
                    m("tr", [
                        m("th", "ID"),
                        m("th", "Text"),
                        m("th", "Actions")
                    ])
                ]),
                m("tbody", [
                    this.data.map((row, index) => {
                        if (this.editingIndex === index) {
                            return m(EditItem, {
                                id: row.id,
                                text: row.text,
                                index: index,
                                save: function(value) {
                                    Home.editingIndex = null;
                                    row.text = value;
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            return m(Item, {
                                id: row.id,
                                text: row.text,
                                index: index,
                                edit: function(index) {
                                    Home.editingIndex = index;
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    })
                ])
            ])
        ]);
    },
    data: [
        {id: 10, text: "Item 1"},
        {id: 20, text: "Item 2"},
        {id: 30, text: "Item 3"}
    ],
    editingIndex: null
};

// Mount Home component
m.mount(document.body, Home);
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Learning Mithril.js</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/mithril/mithril.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>



Thanks!

What makes you think it's editing the whole Home component? Looking at devtools it doesn't look like it

@nanobar I think that because I'm iterating over every data element and checking if its id matches the editingIndex variable. If it matches then EditItem component will be used, else Item component will be used in Home component.

I'm not exactly sure how Mithril works with state changes but it is using a VDOM, that means even if your code is re-executing, it does a diff first to figure out what actually needs updating in the DOM. Personally I'd use VanJS if I wanted something small that didn't need build tooling, or otherwise React or Solid

@nanobar Alright! Thanks for suggestion.
